# MAXScript complete function list?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, maxscript

Writing highlighter for MAXScript. I need list of keywords and functions.

There's a reference for MAXScript:

http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-6FC81BE7-58FF-4C63-8362-0BDCFA9F904C.htm,topicNumber=d30e122065

But it's hard to rip function list from there.
Maybe it could be found somewhere else? I mean, at least listed in one page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such a list available here:
http://forums.cgsociety.org/showpost.php?p=4943422&postcount=20

It has almost 8000 keywords.

You can also make such a list with maxscript:

```
(
fn GatherMaxscriptKeyword =
    (
    out_script=newscript()
    n_stream=stringstream ""
    --//--
    afilter_black=#()
    afilter_blue1=#()
    afilter_blue2=#()
    afilter_Brown=#()
    afilter_Green=#()
    afilter_Gold=#()
    afilter_Red=#()
    afilter_Italic=#()
    --//--
    apropos "" to:n_stream
    seek n_stream 0
    --//--
    while not eof n_stream do
        (
        mtrim=(dotnetobject "system.string" (readLine n_stream)).Split "(" 
        --//--
        if mtrim.count > 1 then
            (
            xtype=(dotnetobject "system.string" mtrim[2]).split ")"
            --//--
            if xtype.count > 1 then
                (--redirect to the wanted array there ...
                appendvalstr=((dotnetobject "system.string" mtrim[1]).Split " ")[1]
                --//--
                case xtype[1] of
                    (
                    "<internal>":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "Array":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "BooleanClass":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "Float":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "Integer":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "MAXScriptFunction":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "MSCustAttribDef":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "MSPluginClass":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "Point2":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "Primitive":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "RCMenu":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "RolloutClass":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "StandardMaterialClass":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "String":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "StructDef":(appendifunique afilter_Brown appendvalstr)
                    "TextureClass":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "UndefinedClass":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "const BipedGeneric":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const BooleanClass":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const Class":(appendifunique afilter_blue2 appendvalstr)
                    "const Color":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const CurveCtlGeneric":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const EmptyClass":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const Float":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const Generic":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const HKey":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const Interface":(appendifunique afilter_Green appendvalstr)
                    "const MAXClass":(appendifunique afilter_blue2 appendvalstr)
                    "const MAXMeshClass":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const MAXScriptFunction":()--empty
                    "const MAXSuperClass":(appendifunique afilter_blue2 appendvalstr)
                    "const MappedGeneric":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const MappedPrimitive":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const MeditMaterialsClass":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const NodeGeneric":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const ObjectSet":(appendifunique afilter_Gold appendvalstr)
                    "const OkClass":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const Point3":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const Primitive":(appendifunique afilter_blue1 appendvalstr)
                    "const Primitive":()--empty
                    "const SelectionSetArray":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const StructDef":(appendifunique afilter_Brown appendvalstr)
                    "const UndefinedClass":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "const UnsuppliedClass":(appendifunique afilter_Italic appendvalstr)
                    "dotNetObject":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "persistent UndefinedClass":(appendifunique afilter_black appendvalstr)
                    "system Array":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system BooleanClass":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Color":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Control":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Float":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Integer":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Integer64":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Interval":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system MAXRootNode":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system MAXTVNode":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system MaterialLibrary":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Name":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system String":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system Time":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system UndefinedClass":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    "system WindowStream":(appendifunique afilter_Red appendvalstr)
                    default:(messagebox "New Class found, Please update the main function." title:"Warning" beep:false)
                    --default:(format(xtype[1]+"\n")to:out_script)
                    )

                )

            )

        )
    --//--Black keyword
    sort afilter_black
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Black"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_black do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )
    --//--blue1 keyword
    sort afilter_blue1
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Blue1"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_blue1 do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )
    --//--blue2 keyword
    sort afilter_blue2
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Blue2"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_blue2 do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )
    --//--Brown keyword
    sort afilter_Brown
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Brown"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_Brown do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )
    --//--Green keyword
    sort afilter_Green
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Green"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_Green do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )
    --//--Gold keyword
    sort afilter_Gold
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Gold"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_Gold do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )
    --//--Red keyword
    sort afilter_Red
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Red"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_Red do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )
    --//--Italic keyword
    sort afilter_Italic
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("Italic"+"\n") to:out_script
    format ("-------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n") to:out_script
    --//--
    for f in afilter_Italic do
        (
        evalstr=(dotnetobject "system.string" f).Split ("\""+"&"+"%")
        --//--
        if evalstr.count == 1 then
            (
            format (evalstr[1]+"\n") to:out_script
            )
        --//--
        )

    )
--//--
GatherMaxscriptKeyword()
ok
)
```

If you have new classes that are not included in the script yet
it will show a messagebox.
The new classes needs to be added to the script if you want the keywords from them.
To avoid showing the messagebox you can comment out that line, or just hold in esc to close them.

Comment: Wow! The userDefineLang.xml from yourl link is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted. maxscript.api from your link contains functions list machine easy-readable but without operators/types, which can be borrowed from userDefineLang.xml, so there's all the needed information.